# A Rottweiler I found in fallout shelter has disappeared

Tags: fallout-shelter

So recently i found Rottweiler on a quest but it won't appear anywhere in my inventory back at the vault, what has happened to it

Answer (score 1):

The things you find in quests do not show up until the team has returned.

Since pets do not show up in the party inventory, you can't tell which team has it until they have returned.

This also applies to any boxes you find.  They are attached to the team, and do not show up until they return.

I think Nuka-Colas are the exception, since they go straight into your stash when you find them in the quest.

Comment: But it didn't even show up anywhere even when they got back

Answer (score 0):

Was it a common Rottweiler? If so, unlike junk, it will be sold if you used the "sell all common items" option once the party returned.